# PL/SQL package not compiling in Toad - insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I try to compile a PL/SQL package in Toad, I'm getting `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` error. However I'm able to compile the same package using sqlplus using the same username and password in the same database. I'm using Windows 7 and use PuTTY to connect to the Unix system in which the Oracle database is present. How can I compile my package in Toad?

Comment: Check his link. http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/f/10/p/25297/55757#55757

Comment: @VimalBhaskar The spool file only contains the following after the package contents: 
`Error at line 1
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Script Terminated on line 1.`

Comment: Are you sure that the current user has the necessary privilege to create a package. By the sound of your error message if feel the necessary privileges are not granted.

Comment: @VimalBhaskar As I have already stated in the question, I am able to compile the package using sqlplus using the same username and password.

Comment: Sounds like your username or database actually isn't the same; or possibly either Toad or SQL\*Plus changes your default schema on logon (look for a login.sql file, or possibly glogin.sql, for SQL\*Plus). What does `select user, sys_context('userenv', 'current_schema') from dual` show in both clients?

Comment: @AlexPoole In both clients the output is same.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have privileges to compile package because you don't have < debug > grant on this package or all packages.

so when you want execute package you need < execute > grant
and when you want to compile package you need < debug > grant

Answer (score 0):

Make certain that your 'CURRENT_SCHEMA' drop down is set to the account with which you are logging in. If it set to something else, TOAD does an alter session before it executes the command.
[image]